# Find all $z$ such that $e^z=6i$

Tags: complex-numbers

Am I on the right track to solving this?

$$e^z=6i$$
Let $w=e^z$

Thus,

$$w=6i$$
$$e^w=e^{6i}$$
$$e^w=\cos(6)+i\sin(6)$$
$$\ln(e^w)=\ln(\cos(6)+i\sin(6))$$
$$w=\ln(\cos(6)+i\sin(6))$$
$$e^z=\ln(\cos(6)+i\sin(6))$$
$$\ln(e^z)=\ln(\ln(\cos(6)+i\sin(6)))$$
$$z=\ln(\ln(\cos(6)+i\sin(6)))$$

I had another method that started by taking the natural log of both sides right away, but that leads to $\arctan(6/0)$, which is undefined...

Comment: Write $6i$ in the form $e^{ia}$ for a better solution

Comment: $i=e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$

Comment: @George isn't that what I did for step #2 after the word "Thus," ?

Comment: Well no because $6i= e^{log6}e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$ and you have not included that anywhere

Comment: @whatwhatwhat No, you made both sides to the equation an exponent of $e$. George wants you to write $6i=e^a e^{bi}=e^{a+bi}$. Here, $e^a$ is the real coefficient, so $e^a=6$ and $e^{bi}$ is the imaginary coefficient, so $e^{bi}=i$. As George said, $a=\ln 6$ and $b=\frac \pi 2$.

Comment: @NobleMushtak woah I've actually never seen that done before. Why is it that we can say $6i=e^ae^{bi}$? Is that a property of some sort?

Comment: any complex number can be represented as $re^{i\theta}$ where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta$ is the angle of the vector representation of $z$.

Comment: What @Eleven-Eleven refers to is related to [Euler's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), which is very useful for solving this problem. It's what you used to change $e^{6i}=\cos(6)+i\sin(6)$.

Comment: But how does $6i=e^ae^{bi}=e^{a+bi}$ relate to $z=re^{i\theta}$? Is it that $e^{i\theta}=e^{0+i\theta}=e^{a+bi}$, where $r=1$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$e^z=6i$.

Let $z=x+iy$.  Note that $e^z=e^x\cdot e^{iy}$

Thus
$$e^z=e^x\cdot e^{iy}=6e^{i\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\right)}$$

So $e^x=6$ and so $x=\ln{6}$.

So $y=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$

Therefore you have as your solutions $z=\ln{6}+i\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\right)$ for integer $k$.

Comment: Why only $\frac \pi 2+2\pi$? Why not just $\frac \pi 2$ or list all solutions with $\frac \pi 2+2\pi k$?

Comment: needed the $k$, thanks.  I just missed it typing fast.

Comment: Wait, this is great and I thank you, but what was wrong with my solution?

Comment: I get that it technically doesn't feel like it's fulfilling the "Find **all** $z$ such that..."

Comment: The $k$ helps represent the infinite solutions for $z$.

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully, from all of these solutions, you know how to solve this problem. Now, let's try doing it your way. You've done everything right so far:
$$z=\ln(\ln(\cos(6)+i\sin(6)))$$

By [Euler's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity), we have $\cos(6)+i\sin(6)=e^{6i}$, so clearly, taking the $\ln$ of this is just $6i$:
$$z=\ln(6i)$$

Now, if we go back to our original equation:
$$e^z=6i$$

The equation we have at the end of all of this is just taking the $\ln$ of both sides of the original equation. Basically, everything you did is all valid, but you basically return to the original equation when we're all done with simplifying everything, which is why you were off-track.

Comment: Ahh...that makes a ton of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $z=x+iy$ and $x$ and $y$ are real.  Then
$$
6i = 6(0 + i) = e^z = e^{x+iy} = e^x e^{iy} = e^x(\cos y + i\sin y).
$$
So $e^x = 6$ and $0+1i=\cos y + i\sin y$.  Thus $\cos y=0$ and $\sin y=1$. So $y = \pi/2$ or $\pi/2+ 2\pi n$ for some integer $n$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

$$6i=e^{\log(6)+i\pi/2+i2n\pi}=e^z$$

Comment: Ah!, first time I've seen you give a solution which may be a little difficult for the OP to understand !.  Anyways, +1

Comment: Shouldn't the last bit in the exponents be just $2\pi n$? Why is there an $i$ there?

Comment: @shailesh Thank you for the up vote!  Much appreciative.  - Mark

Comment: @whatwhatwhat The $i$ is correct since $e^{i2n\pi}=1$ for all integer values of $n$.  But $e^{2\pi n}>1$ for $n\ne0$.

Comment: Ok so you didn't just use the identity $\ln(z)=\ln|z|+iarg(z)+2\pi k$ then?

Comment: I used the fact that $i=e^{i\pi/2+i2n\pi}$, $6=e^{\log(6)}$ and $e^{z_1+z_2}=e^{z_1}e^{z_2}$.